# Working with properties files outside war with Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jboss5.x

I am working on a Spring 3.0.5 web application that accesses LDAP and two databases. I have a properties with configuration information for the LDAP server and that databases, in `applicationContext-security.xml` and `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, but I would like to make it so each server can have different data properties without changing a file in the WAR. Can I somehow put a file somewhere else on the server and still access it from within my application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your context

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${envfile}"/>
```

This will load the properties file located at ${envfile}, a variable you can set with Java's startup paramater like this

```
-Denvfile="file:/var/server/environment.properties"
```

Or maybe in Tomcat's startup script

```
CATALINA_OPTS=" -Denvfile=file:/var/server/environment.properties"
```

Values can be retrieved in your controllers using Springs Value annotation like this:

```
@Values("${myvalue}")
private String myValue;
```

Please note that these features require Spring 3.1, more information [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/)

Good luck!

Comment: I am using Spring version 4. Seems there is no Values annotation. Using Value annotation doesn't populate my values. Also, I am getting message on application startup that property file has been loaded. 2017-04-05 17:27:51 INFO  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:172 - Loading properties file from URL [file:c://java//resources//googleDocsValues.properties]. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<util:properties id="props" location="file:///path/to/server.properties"/>
```